# Counting the minimum number of operations needed to reach a certain number

Tags: algorithm

How should I implement an algorithm for this challenge?

Have three integers, A, B and C.

Your calculator starts off with the number 1, and it must reach C. To do this, you can perform two operations:

- Multiply your number by A (if the result has more than 4 digits, the result will be 1).
- Divide your number by B (integer division).

You must return the minimum number of operations needed to reach C.

Also, your calculator only has four digits, so you can expect A, B and C input to be, at most, 9999.

Example:

```
A = 2, B = 3, C = 10

1*A = 2 
2*A = 4 
4*A = 8 
8*A = 16 
16/B = 5 
5*A = 10
```

So the result would be `6` steps.

---

I once did it by brute-forcing the result (try lots of combinations and grab the one with the least number of steps). That was silly.

Comment: When you say the calculator is limited to four digits, does that include intermediate values?  If I have 600, and do a multiply then a divide, do I get 400 or 66?  Can any numbers be negative?

Comment: Can you multiply beyond 9999? What happens in that case?

Comment: I think for any number greater than 9999/A, multiplying just resets the value to 1.

Comment: Overflow saturates to _1_?  That's the strangest overflow behavior I've ever heard of...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be reduced to a **[shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)** on a graph `G=(V,E)`, where the vertices `V={0,1,2,...,9999}` and `E = { (x,y) | y = x*a, y< 10,000 or y = x /b } U { (x,1) | x*a > 10,000 }`

Now, you need to find shortest path from `1` to your target. It can be done by running a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), [A* Search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) (if you find a good heuristic) or [bi-directional search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search) (which is basically BFS from the target and from the source at the same time)

**EDIT:**

(Note: Original answer contained a bit of a different edges set, that fits a slightly different problem. Either way - the main idea remains)

Comment: bi-directional search is tricky because going backwards is tricky because of the integer division.  In his sample, starting with 10, if the last step is divide, the that came from 30, 31, or 32. The multiple possibilities is something to be noted.

Comment: I do like the idea of keeping track of the path to each vertex, that allows you to quickly bail on obvious failure cases, and (in the bidirectional search), the first full path found is the shortest path.  Very efficient.

Comment: Also note that vertex 0 doesn't actually need tracking because it's NEVER used in the complete path. (Also, first step is always multiplication)

Comment: @MooingDuck Why is it tricky? You just get different number of in-edges for some nodes, and less for the others - but it still can be generated. Given a number `x` and a constant `b`, it is easy to find the set that satisfies `{ y | x/b = y}`, For each `y` in this set you will have `(x,y)` as edge. (There are `b` of those, easy to find them)

Comment: @MooingDuck About 0 and first step - micro-optimizations in my opinion. I'd prefer abstraction and simplification, using a pure graph is simpler, and any shortest path algorithm will never develop this node (0) anyway.

Comment: Yes, I was merely providing caution against the assumption that there is only one numerator X for which `X/B` results in a particular number.  Intuitively it's true, but due to integer division it's false.  And yes, 0 and first-step are micro-optimizations.

Comment: bi-directional search: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b081ac621496d44.
I'd like to try an A*, but I can't think of a heuristic, and I'm certain there _is_ one...

Comment: @MooingDuck Something like `h(x) = x > C ? log_A(C/x) : log_B(x/B)` should work

Comment: what are `log_A` and `log_B`?  `x>C ? C/x : x/B` would work I suppose, but effectively just prioritizes those already closest to the goal, which is going to be a pretty useless heuristic, and way slower than the bi-directional search.

Comment: @MooingDuck log in the base of A/B. The idea is if you have x, and `C=x*A^d` for some `d`, then `C/x = A^d`, and taking out `log_A` gives you `log_A(C/x) = d`. This can give a rough estimate and a lower bound to the number of steps you will need.